# Scrollbars are covering portions of iPad Retina Screenshots from Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, retina-display

I want to take retina iPad screenshots using the simulator, but because it's bigger than my screen the simulator has scrollbars. Those scrollbars are covering part of the UI which means I can't get a clean screenshot.

Any way I can hide the scrollbars in the iPad retina simulator?

Comment: How about rotating the simulator to the left or right and taking a screenshot? If your screen is wide enough to accommodate the height of the simulator window, this eliminates the need to scroll. You can also scale down the simulator window with the Window > Scale menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bobby's suggestion is very useful in general, but not to take retina screenshots. I found in the Edit menu an option to "Copy Screen". If you keep your retina iPad at 100% scaling, then Command-Control-C it will copy the image to your clipboard. Then open up Preview and Command-N (or File->New from Clipboard) and it'll take the data from your clipboard giving you the retina screenshot.

Comment: +1 it works, but its a bit cumbersome. If only the obvious File > Save Screen Shot worked as it should! :/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the window size to only 50%? That makes it fit nicely on my monitor without scroll bars. The hotkey is CMD 3

[image]

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to take a retina screenshot... and if I bring the window scaling down, I can't take a retina screenshot. :)

Comment: D'oh! I was thinking taking a screenshot of the retina simulator, not taking a retina screenshot of the simulator.